# Function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, function, typeerror

I'm writing a program that simulates a lottery game, and I'm stuck at a certain point. I'm trying to match the user's guesses with the numbers on the winning ticket, but my function "checkmatch" apparently takes 2 arguments, but I'm only giving it 1? I know there are similar questions on the site, but I'm a very novice programmer, and the others seemed... a bit above me. This is my program in its entirety (thus far):

```
import random

def main():
random.seed()

#Prompts the user to enter the number of tickets they wish to play.
tickets = int(input("How many lottery tickets do you want?\n"))

#Creates the dictionaries "winning_numbers" and "guess"
winning_numbers = []
guess = []

#Generates the winning lotto numbers.
for i in range(tickets):
    del winning_numbers[:]
    del guess[:]
    a = random.randint(1,30)
    winning_numbers.append(a)

    b = random.randint(1,30)
    while not (b in winning_numbers):
        winning_numbers.append(b)


    c = random.randint(1,30)
    while not (c in winning_numbers):
        winning_numbers.append(c)


    d = random.randint(1,30)
    while not (d in winning_numbers):
        winning_numbers.append(d)

getguess(guess, tickets)
nummatches = checkmatch(guess)
nummisses = checkmiss()

    #print(winning_numbers)

#Gets the guess from the user.
def getguess(guess, tickets):
    del guess[:]

for i in range(tickets):
    bubble = input("What numbers do you want to choose for ticket #"+str(i+1)+"?\n").split(" ")
    guess.append(bubble)

#Checks the user's guesses with the winning numbers.
def checkmatch(winning_numbers, guess):
    match = 0
    for i in range(5):
        if winning_numbers[i] == guess[i]:
            match = match+1

return match
```

And this is the part that is giving me trouble:

```
def checkmatch(winning_numbers, guess):
match = 0
for i in range(5):
    if winning_numbers[i] == guess[i]:
        match = match+1

return match
```

And here is what I get when I try a test run:

```
How many lottery tickets do you want?
3
What numbers do you want to choose for ticket #1?
1 2 3 4 5
What numbers do you want to choose for ticket #2?
1 2 3 4 5
What numbers do you want to choose for ticket #3?
1 2 3 4 5 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ryan/Downloads/Program # 2/Program # 2/lottery.py", line 64, in    <module>
    main()
   File "C:/Users/Ryan/Downloads/Program # 2/Program # 2/lottery.py", line 36, in main
    checkmatch(guess)
TypeError: checkmatch() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: The error is sort of self explanatory; `checkmatch` expects the arguments `winning_numbers` and `guess`, and you're passing it just `guess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
nummatches = checkmatch(guess)
```

In your code `checkmatch` takes 2 arguments `winning_numbers & guess` but when you are calling it you are only giving a single argument.

Like for example

```
>>> def myfunc(str1,str2):
...   print str1+str2
...
>>> myfunc('a','b') #takes 2 argument and concatenates
ab
>>> myfunc('a') # only one given so ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: myfunc() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't in the function definition. It's here:

```
nummatches = checkmatch(guess)
```

In the error statement, you'll notice that there are line numbers. The line causing the error is at the very bottom of the error statement. The problem is on line 36; if you have a text editor that shows line numbers, you'll find it easer to figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

In your function definition for checkmatch, you explicitly tell Python to expect two arguments whenever this function is called:

```
def checkmatch(winning_numbers, guess):
   ...
```

In the body of your program, however, you call it with only one argument:

```
nummatches = checkmatch(guess)
```

Since you are not providing the winning_numbers argument to checkmatch, you get the error.

It appears that you are doing this because you have already used winning_numbers in the body of your main program.  This is where the actual mistake is, you are presuming that because the variable in the body of your program has the same name as the variable in your function definition that the variable winning_numbers is automatically being passed in.

The winning_numbers argument in the function definition is a **local variable** to the function checkmatch, it merely tells Python to expect a value to be given by the user in that position when the function is called, and then allows that name to be used to represent that value inside the function definition itself.  The winning_numbers list you have in your main program, however, is an example of a **global variable** and since your function definition reuses that exact same name you're giving Python illogical directions to follow, hence the error.

To fix, either a) pass in the variable explicitly:

```
nummatches = checkmatch(winning_numbers, guess)
```

... or b) properly use the global variable.

```
def checkmatch(guess):
    global winning_numbers
    ...
```

I would suggest, however, that you're best off reading up more on Python namespaces and global vs local variables, and when to use each.

Also, as an aside, it is generally not a good idea to use the **del** builtin except in very specific cases.  You have already assigned your variables to be empty lists, there's no need in your code's context to manually delete their contents again.